# Laravel Voyager - How to select a default role when creating a user

Tags: php, laravel, admin, voyager

When I create a user, I would like to set a role as selected and display it in the dropdown as selected when opening the interface.

I suppose I should edit the relationship.blade.php file, but I hope there is a better way to do it, maybe by changing the details in the BREAD or in the DataRowsTableSeeder.php file, or adding something to the models. Please help!

[image]

```
php: ^7.2.5
laravel/framework: ^7.0
tcg/voyager: ^1.4
```